# Delete duplicates in list of interpolating functions

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, interpolation

I have a list of several hundreds of `InterpolatingFunction` generated by numerical continuations based on different starting points. A list can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=uhcd&id=0B5VytYqoTlgtYXY3TkpwVEVjRWM) [68Mb, that's what I needed to have something representative].

My problem is easily understood by plotting the `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
data = Import["list.m"];
Table[With[{fun = data[[i]]}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[fun[[1]], {t, fun[[2, 1]], fun[[2, 2]]}]], {i, 1, Length@data}]
```

[image]

In this figure, I manually circled "similar" curves. Two curves are considered "similar" when they overlap on an interval of non-zero length (let's say of length 1). For obvious reasons, I'd like to keep only one curve of each kind; only the longest one should be conserved. So in this example it would give me only 5 curves (one for each color). The difficulty is that each curve has a different parametrization, so the range of the parameter `t` is arbitrary (it has at least $0$ and is at most $[-100,100]$) and `@bbgodfrey`'s approach fails now that I have added additional curves: it measures a larger difference between the number 1 and number -2 (second to last) than between number 1 and number 7 (the yellow one).

The following approach works, but I'm wondering if there are more efficient alternatives. For example, the above figure was generated in about 3 seconds, so maybe a graphical-based strategy could be better.

In the following code, I compare the point on the first curve corresponding to parameter $t=0$ to the closest point of each other curve. Note: if different curves may intersect in multiple points (e.g. curves red and yellow), the probability that they intersect at a specified location (here, the point of curve 1 for $t=0$) is extremely small.

```
Table[With[{pt0 = data[[1, 1]] /. t -> 0, fun = data[[i, 1]], 
tmin = data[[i, 2, 1]], tmax = data[[i, 2, 2]]},
NMinimize[{Norm[pt0 - fun], tmin < t < tmax}, t][[1]]], {i, Length@data}] // Chop

 (* {0, 0, 0, 0.883892, 0.883892, 3.17593, 2.97059, 0, 0, 0.883892, 0, 2.58457,
  0.883892, 2.97059, 2.58457, 2.58457, 2.58457, 0, 2.97059, 3.17593, 0,
  3.17593, 0.883892, 1.59063, 3.17593, 2.97059,  0.883892, 3.17593, 0, 3.17593} *)
```

Comment: The two curves have different domains of definition. If so, your "duplicate" condition is that they should be "coincident" (which should then be defined as appropriate) at the intersection of the two domains; did I understand your requirement correctly?

Comment: How about evaluating them at a set of random points?

Comment: @J.M. Absolutely. We could say that if half of a curve is part of the other, then only the other should be conserved, for example.

Comment: @mikado Their parametrizations are different, so that's not so easy: for $t=0$ you could get $(0,0,0)$ for one curve and $(1,2,3)$ for another, even if both curves are the same (= they carry the same information).

Comment: Although I could not load `Mathematica.m` with `data = Get["https...`, as in the question, I was able to download the 8 MB file directly to disk.  Unfortunately, Mathematica 11.0.1 has been struggling for over 45 minutes to load the code.  Therefore, I suggest that you provide a notebook file with say, ten `InterpolatingFunctions` that illustrate the issues involved with your question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey That's really strange, I checked the code `data=Get[...` twice, on two different machines and with MMA 10.0.3 and 11.0.0. Once the file is downloaded, the code should load in a few seconds. I tried to make a notebook file but I can't just save the `InterpolatingFunctions` with `data={{InterpolatingFunction...`. The whole code to produce the interpolating functions is too long to include it. Would you like me to try with only 2 interpolating functions? It should give a 2.5Mb file.

Comment: @bbgodfrey What if you download [this file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5VytYqoTlgtUFdwZ2Flel9ITDA) and load it with `DumpGet["temp.mx"]`? I saved it with `DumpSave`.

Comment: I just ran one of the 15 `InterpolatingFunctions` by loading the whole file into Windows Notepad and copying one of the functions into Mathematica, which worked well.  Next, I shall try copying the whole file from Notepad into Mathematica.

Comment: The approached just described worked.

Comment: @anderstood, OK, but what criterion do you want to use to pick which of the two should be retained? Or does it not matter which of the two is picked?

Comment: @J.M. It does not really matter. Ideally, the longest (for the euclidian norm), but that requires an integration. This I could do it by myself.

Comment: I guess you can easy take the interpolation boundary from each function to estimate the range of interpolation. Than you can calculate the cross-correlation of one with others. If it correlates, you should exclude from the list those which have shorter range of arguments..

Comment: @Rom38 By interpolation boundary, you mean the interval where the parameter of the interpolating function lives? The thing is that two interpolating functions can correspond to the same curve, one being defined over $[0,1]$ and the other one over $[-5.5,-2]$ for example. So correlating them is not easy.

Comment: @anderstood, Yes, I'm speaking about intervals of existence of interpolation function. You already have the boundaries, thus, you can take a pair of IFs with their intervals and correlate them inside a shortest of chosen ranges..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach works, seems quite efficient, but relies on the assumption that the curves do not pass "too close" from each other; in particular, they should not intersect. It is *not* conservative, because if two different curves intersect, one of them will be lost. But this approach works in any dimension.

The idea is to take 100 points (actually, 101...) of each curve and compute the minimal distance between the two lists with `DistanceMatrix`. If it is smaller than a given threshold (here, 0.001), then the curves are considered identical (returns `True`).

```
areSolsEqualQ[sol1_, sol2_] := 
 Block[{tab1, tab2, domain1 = sol1[[1]]["Domain"] // Flatten, 
   domain2 = sol2[[1]]["Domain"] // Flatten},
  tab1 = Table[
    Through[sol1[t]], {t, Subdivide[domain1[[1]], domain1[[2]], 100]}];
  tab2 = Table[
    Through[sol2[t]], {t, Subdivide[domain2[[1]], domain2[[2]], 100]}];
  min = Min[DistanceMatrix[tab1, tab2]];
  If[min < 0.001, True, False]]
```

This comparison function can then be used with `Union` using the `SameTest` method:

```
Union[data, SameTest -> (areSolsEqualQ[#1, #2] &)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The question describes the curves defined by triplets of `InterpolatingFunction`s as either largely overlapping or well separated in space, and the five curves provided in the file available for download certainly have this character.  This suggests the following approach.  Define

```
compare[n1_, n2_] := Module[{t1 = Max[data[[n1, 2, 1]], data[[n2, 2, 1]]], 
    t2 = Min[data[[n1, 2, 2]], data[[n2, 2, 2]]]}, 
    Mean@Table[Norm[data[[n1, 1]] - data[[n2, 1]]] /. t -> t0, {t0, t1, t2, (t2 - t1)/10}]]
```

which measures the distance between curves over their overlapping parameter ranges.  Applying this function pairwise to the five curves yields

```
Table[compare[n1, n2], {n1, 5}, {n2, 5}] 

(* {{0, 1.07761, 2.16842, 31.53, 31.508}, 
    {1.07761, 0, 1.0965, 31.5188, 31.5321}, 
    {2.16842, 1.0965, 0, 31.5043, 31.5018}, 
    {31.53, 31.5188, 31.5043, 0, 0.485946}, 
    {31.508, 31.5321, 31.5018, 0.485946, 0}} *)
```

This approach effectively distinguishes among two groups of curves, the first three and the last two.  Of course, if the actual set of curves to be sorted contains curves that are neither close nor far apart, then this approach may not work as well.

Although the `Table` above entails 25 calls to `compare`, five would have sufficed.  For large sets of curves, overlapping curves would be eliminated as they were identified.  At worst, the number of calls would be `n(n-1)/2`, if no curves largely overlapped.  At best, the number of calls would be `n-1`, if all curves largely overlapped.

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that if there are two (or more) parametrizations of the same curve which are very different, it may fail. For example if $f$ and $g$ have the same graph but $f(t)=g(t+50)$. I'll try on larger sets to see if this suffices for my case. Thank you.

Comment: @anderstood  If parameter offset is a major issue, it can be accommodated by doing the comparison with a range of offsets and finding the one, if any, for which `compare` is small.  If parameter dilatation is the issue instead, then different dilations can be tried in the same way, although the cost of doing so could be high.  Without have more information on the curves, I would suggest first eliminating duplicates as I did in my answer, then running a second pass eliminating similar curves with offset parameters, and finally eliminating similar curves with dilated parameters.

Comment: @anderstood  A more robust but potentially much more expensive approach would be to find the minimum distance between a point on one curve and the entire second curve,  Then, if it is small, do the same for several more points.  If all are small, a match can be assumed.  I recommend that you create a file of many typical curves, each defined much more coarsely, so that I and others have something to work with.  For now, all I can add is that my solution solves the problem as embodied in the sample curves provided.

Comment: @anderstood, is it possible for "non-duplicate" curves to intersect in more than one point, without coinciding?

Comment: @J.M. They could have more than two intersections, but this almost never happens if you don't precisely look for an intersection (if you choose a point on a curve and another curve passes through this point, then both curves are the same). That's the approach I used in my edit.